# Кириллица в TextView отображается не правильно в Android приложении

Tags: android, android-studio

Не могу понять в чем причина, почему кириллица передаваемое в `TextView` отображается ромбиками? Считываю обычный текстовый файл по ниже приведенному коду. Возвращаю `result` в `TextView`. В чем проблема, подскажите.
Кодировку в Android studio в разделе File Encoding поставил UTF8.

```
fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(MainActivity.DISCOUNTS);
        bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

        byte[] input = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
        while ((fileInputStream.read(input)) != -1) {
            result += new String(input);
        }
```

Comment: А сам файл то у вас в какой кодировке?)

Comment: Обычный txt,  сделанный в Windows

Comment: Контейнер и ОС эт конечно хорошо, но я про кодировку спрашивал, а она на русской винде в блокноте CP1251 по умолчанию. А ваш вариант чтения рассчитывает на UTF-8. Счас отвечу как исправить надо...

Comment: Word показывает CP1251.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам просто надо указать кодировку файла при преобразовании его в текст:

```
    fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(MainActivity.DISCOUNTS);
    bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

    byte[] input = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
    while ((fileInputStream.read(input)) != -1) {
        result += new String(input, Charset.forName("cp1251"));
        // возможно вместо "cp1251" нужно юзать "windows-1251", точно не знаю как эта кодирова оффициально обзывается
    }
```